# Copy from docker to host inside CI build

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I would like to know if it would be possible to somehow copy file/folder from inside docker to host but copying itself is executed form inside docker.

The reason is that, for example:

- Commit file to repo
- CI kicks in
- Docker installs dependencies, builds the website files
- Website files is copied from docker to /var/www/my-website (host)

When I was searching for a solution I've seen this command a lot `docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target` however this is executed from HOST. I want to make the whole process automated.

Possible solution of course is to not use docker but straight-up SSH, that's what I'm doing now, but that is not the best option IMO.

Here is example of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that will explain what I want to achieve.

```
image: ubuntu:16.04

build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - apt-get update
        - apt-get upgrade -yy
        - apt-get install hugo -yy # Static site generator
        - hugo build # Build the website
        - cp -R ./build/* /var/www/my-website/ # Copy to the web root
```

Here is my runner configuration

```
[[runners]]
  name = "DOCKER-TEST"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/ci"
  token = "{{token}}"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ubuntu:16.04"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/home/stan:/builds/stanislavromanov/test-docker:rw"]
  [runners.cache]
    Insecure = false
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to set a Docker [volume](https://docs.docker.com/v1.10/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/) where a directory in the container is mounted to a directory of the host.

In case of GitLab CI runners this can be specified during runner registration or later by modifying */etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml*. Example:

```
[[runners]]
  url = "https://gitlab.com/ci"
  token = TOKEN
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ubuntu:16.04"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/path/to/bind/from/host:/path/to/bind/in/container:rw"]
```

See [documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md) for more info.

Comment: Hey, I've tried this one ` volumes = ["/cache", "/builds/stanislavromanov/test-docker:/home/stan:rw"]` and didn't saw any file created in my home dir. Also tried to copy file directly like so `cp myCoolFile /usr/stan/myCoolFile`. Am I doing something wrong? Here is the repo https://gitlab.com/stanislavromanov/test-docker/

Comment: The volume definition is supposed to be *host_path:container_path* while it seems to me you have set up the opposite.

Comment: Hey, I've added my configuration to the answer, does it looks correct to you?

Comment: It looks correct but I have to admit I don't really understand why you would set the whole home folder to be mounted. I would just set */home/stan/builds* of the host to correlate with e.g. */output* in the container. Then the script would copy the whole build folder while naming it using the commit reference: `cp -R ./build "/output/$CI_BUILD_REF"` and this would appear as a new subdirectory in */home/stan/builds* on the host.

Answer (score 4):

Copying from a container to the host is not possible with something like `docker cp`. What you can do though is to mount the host-directory into the container, e.g.:

```
$ docker run ... -v /var/www/my-website:/website-on-host ...
```

and adapt your `cp` command in `.gitlab-ci.yml` as follows:

```
cp -R ./build/* /website-on-host/ # Copy to the web root
```